# Finding an upper bound for an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I don't understand this exercise:

> Let $f\in C^\infty$, $y_0$ given and $f$ Lipschitz and
>   $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t))\qquad y(0)=y_0\qquad t\in [0,T]$$
>   Find an uper bound for $$e_0=y(t_1)-y(0)-hf(0,y(0))$$
>   with use of $$w_1(y,h)=\max_{|t-\sigma|\leq h}|y(t)-y(\sigma)|,t,\sigma \in [0,T]\\w_2(y,h)=\max_{|t-\sigma|\leq h}|y'(t)-y'(\sigma)|,t,\sigma \in [0,T]$$

Now for me this exercise doesn't make much sense, since
$$y(t_1)-y(0)\leq \max_{|t-\sigma|\leq h}|y(t)-y(\sigma)|$$
So $w_1(y,h)-hf(0,y(0))$ is already a bound and same for $$y(t_{n+1})-y(t_{n-1})\leq 2\max_{|t-\sigma|\leq h}|y(t)-y(\sigma)|$$
Am I missing something?

Comment: This looks somewhat like a step in the development of an error bound for a numeric integration method, that is, eventually you will have a bound on the difference between the sum of the first $k$ integration steps and the actual integral value $y(t_k) - y(0)$ over the same interval. Looking ahead might clear things up a bit. A couple of other things: I think you want $w_2$ rather than $f$ in your expression of an upper bound; and it seems odd that the formula for $e_n$ evaluates $f$ at the same place as the formula for $e_0.$

Comment: I don't think that's where this was intended to go. But I don't have the ability to peek ahead in your book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get for example, using $y'(0)=f(0,y(0))$,
\begin{align}
\|y(h)-y(0)-hy'(0)\|
&=\|\int_0^h(y'(s)-y'(0))\,ds\|\\
&\le\int_0^h\|y'(s)-y'(0))\|\,ds\\
&\le h·w_2(y,h)
\end{align}

Comment: I see, thank you very much, this was extremly helpful. Now I understand the exercises!